# Docker compose fails

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I wrote a node server and I'd like to wrap it with docker compose for development (later I'll add more services).
This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
    server:
        image: node:alpine
        volumes:
            - ./
        working_dir: /.
        environment:
            NODE_ENV: development
        ports:
            - 8009:8009
        command: npm run dev
```

When running `docker-compose up` I get:

```
Recreating bed_server_1 ... error

ERROR: for bed_server_1  Cannot start service server: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "open /proc/self/fd: no such file or directory": unknown

ERROR: for server  Cannot start service server: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "open /proc/self/fd: no such file or directory": unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

I am using mac.
Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error may occurs because of the volume. You should try to remove these lines:

```
volumes:
    - ./
```

Then try to map the folder to a volume declared in the `docker-compose` file, like that:

```
services:
    server:
        image: node:alpine
        volumes:
            - test_volume:./
        working_dir: /.
        environment:
            NODE_ENV: development
        ports:
            - 8009:8009
        command: npm run dev
volumes:
    test_volume:
        external: true
```

Answer (score 1):

The volumes should be mapped to a folder inside the container. `./` doesn't say where the folder is to be mapped inside the container. To say that, change the volumes to `./:/app` to map `./` directory from host machine to `/app` directory inside docker and update `working_dir` as below:

```
        volumes:
            - ./:/app
        working_dir: /app
```